# Apache Mina + SSL + Android not working

Tags: java, android, ssl, mina

I'm developing an Android app using Apache Mina for network IO. Non-SSL connections (reading, writing) work fine, but as soon as I add an SSL filter things stop working.
I also tried pure SSL sockets and they work fine.

This is my Mina connection code (in a separate networking thread):

```
    IoConnector connector = new NioSocketConnector();
    connector.getSessionConfig().setReadBufferSize(2048);
    SocketSessionConfig cfg = (SocketSessionConfig)connector.getSessionConfig();
    cfg.setTcpNoDelay(true);

    SslContextFactory f = new SslContextFactory();
    f.setTrustManagerFactory(new BogusTrustManagerFactory());
    f.setProtocol("SSL");

    try {
      filter = new SslFilter(f.newInstance(), true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Exception: ", e);
      return;
    }
    filter.setUseClientMode(true);

    connector.getFilterChain().addLast("sslFilter", filter);
    connector.getFilterChain().addLast("logger", new LoggingFilter());
    connector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new TextLineCodecFactory(Charset.forName("ASCII"))));


    connector.setHandler(new MinaClientHandler());
    ConnectFuture future = connector.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.1.9", 7072));
    future.awaitUninterruptibly();

    if (!future.isConnected())
    {
      Log.d(TAG, "not connected, return");
      return;
    }
    IoSession session = future.getSession();
    session.getConfig().setUseReadOperation(true);
    session.getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
    //System.out.println(session.read().getMessage());

    Log.d(TAG, "after writting");
    connector.dispose();
```

In my IoHandlerAdapter I have the following override:

```
@Override
public void sessionOpened(IoSession session)
{
  session.write(IoBuffer.wrap(data));  // byte array
}
```

Not my actual code, but it reproduces the problem.

On the server side I see that the connection is accepted an the handshake succeeds. But on the client side nothing is sent over the socket. I have tried the same code in a desktop Java application and it also works.

Also if I move the write call just after `IoSession session = future.getSession();` the same thing happens.

Has anyone had similar issues? Are there known issues with Mina on Android? Am I missing some session config options?
Since normal SSL sockets work, that is a workaround, but I would rather not rewrite all my networking code.